# Bigquery Find which table an entry belongs to

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm cleaning my production dataset, to do, i'm looking for some useless entries.

```
SELECT count(pid_like) FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(DATASET.TABLE_PRODUCTION_, DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -30, 'DAY'),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) where c1 is null and c2 is null and c3 is null and c4 is null
```

So I want to delete entries where c1, c2, c3 and c4 are null.

Before I made on the last 30 tables the cleaning as:

```
# done for each last 30 tables
DELETE FROM DATASET.TABLE_PRODUCTION_YYYYMMDD where c1 is null and c2 is null and c2 is null and c4 is null.
```

But after the cleaning, some useless entries remain but I can't find on what table they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to find which tables have rows with nulls:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  _TABLE_SUFFIX AS suffix,
  COUNT(*) AS null_count
FROM `DATASET.TABLE_PRODUCTION_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AND
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE()) AND
  c1 IS NULL AND
  c2 IS NULL AND
  c3 IS NULL AND
  c4 IS NULL
GROUP BY suffix
HAVING null_count > 0
ORDER BY null_count DESC;
```

It will return the suffixes (dates) with null rows and the counts.

Comment: Maybe this one? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix. Here is FORMAT_DATE, but you can find other functions here as well: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_date